# How to remove rows with all zeros in R without getting Error in rowSums 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, bioinformatics

My goal is the same as that explained here: 
[How to remove rows with 0 values using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055788/how-to-remove-rows-with-0-values-using-r)

I have created df1 by reading a .csv file containg about 50000 rows, many with 0 0 0 0 in the FPKM columns. 
Input data frame:

> ```
> tracking_id   gene_id locus   FPKM-R1 FPKM-R2 FPKM-R3 FPKM-R4
> NR_1  DDX1    chr1:1  0.031   0.056   0.0045  0.0345
> NR_2  DDX2    chr1:2  3.06588 3.65986 5.32698 3.6996
> NR_3  DDX3    chr1:4  0   0   0   0
> NR_4  DDX4    chr1:4  0   0   0   0
> NM_5  DDX5    chr1:5  0   0   0.046985    0
> ```

Desired output data frame:

> ```
> tracking_id   gene_id locus   FPKM-R1 FPKM-R2 FPKM-R3 FPKM-R4
> NR_1  DDX1    chr1:1  0.031   0.056   0.0045  0.0345
> NR_2  DDX2    chr1:2  3.06588 3.65986 5.32698 3.6996
> NM_5  DDX5    chr1:5  0   0   0.046985    0
> ```

I am trying to apply the rowSums solution as proposed in the past post:

```
df2 <- df1[rowSums(df1[, -3]) > 0, ]
```

but am getting

```
Error in rowSums(df1[, -3]) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I have checked that the data in the four FPKM-R columns is numeric. I'm at a loss as to why this error is occurring and what I can do to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you want `df1[,-(1:3)]`?

Comment: @jap. If there are more columns and character columns are scattered,`df1[rowSums(df1[sapply(df1,is.numeric)])>0,]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want examine all columns but the first three.

`df1[, -3]` is the data frame with the third column removed.  You want to remove columns 1, 2 and 3, which is represented by `1:3` in R, giving this expression:

```
df2 <- df1[rowSums(df1[, -(1:3)]) > 0, ]
```