# How to build function will name the column with length of x in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to build a function which can search words in the text vector. But sometimes the vector will contain more than 10 elements(ps: the length of vectors can vary). So I want to name those columns according to the length of function "x". The name should be "str1","str2","str3"...and so on. How can I do it? Thank you for helping : )

```
> myfun <- function(x){
>   
>   word5<- c("my",9,6,5,3,4,3)
>   
qq <- function(x){
>     str_count(x, pattern = word5)
>   }
>   
>   Freq <- sapply(x, FUN = qq)
>   
output1 <- data.frame(word5,Freq)
>   output1
>   
> }
> 
> u <- c("my god","my love my", "my my my")


>myfun(u)
```

The results should be like this

```
>   word5    str1       str2      str3
> 1     my      1          2        3
> 2      9      0          0        0
> 3      6      0          0        0
> 4      5      0          0        0
> 5      3      0          0        0
> 6      4      0          0        0
> 7      3      0          0        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:?

```
require(stringr)

myfun <- function(u) {
  n <- seq_along(u)
  word5 <- c("my", "god", 6, 5, 3, 4, 3)
  qq <- function(x) {
    str_count(x, pattern = word5)
  }
  Freq <- sapply(u, FUN = qq)
  output1 <- data.frame(word5, Freq)
  colnames(output1)[-1] <- paste0("str", n)
  output1
}

u <- c("my god","my love my", "my my my")


myfun(u)
#   word5 str1 str2 str3
# 1    my    1    2    3
# 2   god    1    0    0
# 3     6    0    0    0
# 4     5    0    0    0
# 5     3    0    0    0
# 6     4    0    0    0
# 7     3    0    0    0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You perfectly solve my problem. And I have one more question. If I want to delete those rows which contain number 0. How can I do it?

Comment: @YouZhou https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055788/how-to-remove-rows-with-0-values-using-r

Comment: Thank you. Have a nice day : )

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
library(tidyverse)

word_searcher <- function(vec_to_search, pattern) {
  word_count <- stringr::str_count(vec_to_search, pattern)

  setNames(word_count, paste0("str_", seq_along(word_count))) %>%
    enframe() %>%
    spread(name, value) %>%
    mutate(word5 = pattern) %>%
    select(word5, everything())

}

u <- c("my god","my love my", "my my my", "my", "pop", "pip my")
word_searcher(u, "my")


# # A tibble: 1 x 7
#   word5 str_1 str_2 str_3 str_4 str_5 str_6
#   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1    my     1     2     3     1     0     1
```

We get the counts, set the names of the counts as a function of the length of the vector, and then simply turn that into a data frame with the correct column ordering.

You can use the function to pass vectors of sentences and patterns that you want to get in a loop and then `bind_rows` everything together.

Answer (score 0):

#### Your data

```
u <- c("my god","my love my", "my my my")
word5<- c("my","god",6,5,3,4)
```

#### Solution

```
library(stringr)
ans <- rbind.data.frame(t(sapply(word5, function(x) str_count(u, x))))
```

#### Output

```
    V1 V2 V3
my   1  2  3
god  1  0  0
6    0  0  0
5    0  0  0
3    0  0  0
4    0  0  0
```