# How to remove rows where all columns are zero using dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```r
dat <- structure(list(`A-XXX` = c(1.51653275922944, 0.077037240321129, 
0), `fBM-XXX` = c(2.22875185527511, 0, 0), `P-XXX` = c(1.73356698481106, 
0, 0), `vBM-XXX` = c(3.00397859609183, 0, 0)), .Names = c("A-XXX", 
"fBM-XXX", "P-XXX", "vBM-XXX"), row.names = c("BATF::JUN_AHR", 
"BATF::JUN_CCR9", "BATF::JUN_IL10"), class = "data.frame")

dat 
#>                     A-XXX  fBM-XXX    P-XXX  vBM-XXX
#> BATF::JUN_AHR  1.51653276 2.228752 1.733567 3.003979
#> BATF::JUN_CCR9 0.07703724 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
#> BATF::JUN_IL10 0.00000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

I can remove the row with all column zero with this command:

```r
> dat <- dat[ rowSums(dat)!=0, ]
> dat
                    A-XXX  fBM-XXX    P-XXX  vBM-XXX
BATF::JUN_AHR  1.51653276 2.228752 1.733567 3.003979
BATF::JUN_CCR9 0.07703724 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

But how can I do it with dplyr's pipe style?

Comment: You said you wanted to keep the row names.  That is what my code is doing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a dplyr option:

```
library(dplyr)
filter_all(dat, any_vars(. != 0))

#       A-XXX  fBM-XXX    P-XXX  vBM-XXX
#1 1.51653276 2.228752 1.733567 3.003979
#2 0.07703724 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Here we make use of the logic that if any variable is not equal to zero, we will keep it. It's the same as removing rows where all variables are equal to zero.

Regarding row.names:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% rownames_to_column() %>% filter_at(vars(-rowname), any_vars(. != 0))
#         rowname      A-XXX  fBM-XXX    P-XXX  vBM-XXX
#1  BATF::JUN_AHR 1.51653276 2.228752 1.733567 3.003979
#2 BATF::JUN_CCR9 0.07703724 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Comment: Need to preserve the row names. How can I modify your code?

Comment: @scamander, see my update. In general, you don't want to work with row.names when using dplyr (or data.table). Instead, always store that information in a separate column.

Comment: how to do that with dplyr and across() rather than _all?

Comment: @Art, you can use `if_any`, I found an example in the `across()` help page. I tailored this example and posted a new answer.

Answer (score 4):

##### Update 2022-11-11

With the latest tidyverse packages, `across() in filter() is deprecated`. The updated solution now is:

```
data %>% filter(if_all(everything(.), ~. != 0))
```

---

##### Old solution (depecrated)

Adding to the answer by @mgrund,
a shorter alternative with dplyr 1.0.0 is:

```
# Option A:
data %>% filter(across(everything(.)) != 0))

# Option B:
data %>% filter(across(everything(.), ~. != 0))
```

Explanation: 
`across()` checks for every tidy_select variable, which is `everything()` representing every column. In Option A, every column is checked if not zero, which adds up to a complete row of zeros in every column. In Option B, on every column, the formula (~) is applied which checks if the current column is zero.

EDIT:
As `filter` already checks by row, you don't need `rowwise()`. This is different for `select` or `mutate`.

IMPORTANT:
In Option A, it is crucial to write `across(everything(.)) != 0`, 
and NOT
`across(everything(.) != 0))`!

Reason: 
`across` requires a tidyselect variable (here `everything()`), not a boolean (which would be `everything(.) != 0)`)

Comment: Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `logical`.
i It must be numeric or character.
i Input `..1` is `across(everything() != 0)`.
i The error occurred in row 1.

Comment: You are right, my version only works without `rowwise`. Corrected!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new `if_any()`. I tailored an example found in the documentation of `if_any()`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
dat <- structure(list(`A-XXX` = c(1.51653275922944, 0.077037240321129, 
                                  0), `fBM-XXX` = c(2.22875185527511, 0, 0), `P-XXX` = c(1.73356698481106, 
                                                                                         0, 0), `vBM-XXX` = c(3.00397859609183, 0, 0)), .Names = c("A-XXX", 
                                                                                                                                                   "fBM-XXX", "P-XXX", "vBM-XXX"), row.names = c("BATF::JUN_AHR", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "BATF::JUN_CCR9", "BATF::JUN_IL10"), class = "data.frame")
dat
#>                     A-XXX  fBM-XXX    P-XXX  vBM-XXX
#> BATF::JUN_AHR  1.51653276 2.228752 1.733567 3.003979
#> BATF::JUN_CCR9 0.07703724 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
#> BATF::JUN_IL10 0.00000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000

dat %>% 
  rownames_to_column("ID") %>% 
  filter(if_any(!matches("ID"), ~ . != 0)) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("ID")
#>                     A-XXX  fBM-XXX    P-XXX  vBM-XXX
#> BATF::JUN_AHR  1.51653276 2.228752 1.733567 3.003979
#> BATF::JUN_CCR9 0.07703724 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

We could use `reduce` from `purrr` to get the sum of rows and `filter` the dataset based on the logical vector

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
    reduce(`+`) %>%
    {. != 0} %>% 
   filter(dat, .)
#       A-XXX  fBM-XXX    P-XXX  vBM-XXX
#1 1.51653276 2.228752 1.733567 3.003979
#2 0.07703724 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

NOTE: Within the `%>%`, the row.names gets stripped off.  It may be better to create a new column or assign row.names later

---

If we need the row names as well, then create a row names column early and then use that to change the row names at the end

```
dat %>%
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
  filter(rowSums(.[-1]) != 0) %>% 
  `row.names<-`(., .[['rn']]) %>% select(-rn)
#                   A-XXX  fBM-XXX    P-XXX  vBM-XXX
#BATF::JUN_AHR  1.51653276 2.228752 1.733567 3.003979
#BATF::JUN_CCR9 0.07703724 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Comment: thanks. Actually my initial `dat` is a long series of pipe. How can  I modify your code so that `filter(dat,.)` won't compate.

Comment: correct your `filter` contains `dat` where as my dat is long series of pipe.

Comment: thanks but doing that remove the row names. I want to preserve the row names.

Comment: @scamander Do you have any other operations after this step?  Because, even if we keep the row.names, it will get stripped off in the next chain

Answer (score 1):

Here is a third option that uses `purrr::pmap` to generate the indices of whether or not all rows are zero. Definitely less compact than `filter_at`, but opens up options for interesting and complex conditions using `pmap`!

```r
dat <- structure(list(`A-XXX` = c(1.51653275922944, 0.077037240321129, 
                                  0), `fBM-XXX` = c(2.22875185527511, 0, 0), `P-XXX` = c(1.73356698481106, 
                                                                                         0, 0), `vBM-XXX` = c(3.00397859609183, 0, 0)), .Names = c("A-XXX", 
                                                                                                                                                   "fBM-XXX", "P-XXX", "vBM-XXX"), row.names = c("BATF::JUN_AHR", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "BATF::JUN_CCR9", "BATF::JUN_IL10"), class = "data.frame")

library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  bind_cols(all_zero = pmap_lgl(., function(rowname, ...) all(list(...) == 0))) %>%
  filter(all_zero == FALSE) %>%
  `rownames<-`(.$rowname) %>%
  select(-rowname, -all_zero)
#>                     A-XXX  fBM-XXX    P-XXX  vBM-XXX
#> BATF::JUN_AHR  1.51653276 2.228752 1.733567 3.003979
#> BATF::JUN_CCR9 0.07703724 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Created on 2018-03-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option using the row-wise operations of dplyr (with `col1,col2,col3` defining three exemplary columns for which the rowwise sum is calculated):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    filter(sum(c(col1,col2,col3)) != 0)
```

Alternatively, if you have tons of variables (columns) to select you can also use the tidyverse selection syntax via:

```
df <- df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    filter(sum(c_across(col1:col3)) != 0)
```

For details see: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html