# Remove rows in a dataframe if 0 is found X number of times

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a large dataframe which looks like the toy example below.

```
          Sample1        Sample2      Sample3      Sample4
  Gene1     0               0            0            1 
  Gene2     1               0            0            1 
  Gene3     1               1            1            0
```

I want to remove all genes which were equal to 0 in at least two samples. Only Gene3 should remain.

The answer in this question was close but not specific enough for my question.
[How to remove rows with 0 values using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055788/how-to-remove-rows-with-0-values-using-r)

```
df[apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x) !all(x==0)),]
```

Can it be adjusted to remove rows is x==0 two or more times?

Comment: `df[!rowSums(df == 0) > 2, , drop = FALSE]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one-liner. Note that `rowSums` is coded in C and is fast.

```
df[!rowSums(df == 0) >= 2, , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Re-reading the question it seems as if @Krutik asked to remove rows if the number of zeroes >= 2?

Comment: @rps1227 You are right, corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

```
df[-which(apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x == 0) > 2)),]
```

or:

```
subset(df,!rowSums(df == 0) > 2)
```